# id="this" in a href link to a css stylesheet?

Tags: css, content-management-system, stylesheet, href

```
<link href="assets/theme.css" id="this" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What does id="this" target and how does this work in a href link to a stylesheet?

From a tutorial i downloaded legally i couldnt find any reference to the html or javascript. is it syntax from a CMS?

Comment: It's just an id for the `link` element, it's not used with the loaded style sheet for anything.

Comment: Please explain why I have a -2 vote down?!

Comment: Show yourself and give a valid reason for the mark down!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not target anything; it just assigns a unique identifier to the element – that’s what the `id` attribute does. It does not have any default effect on anything. It could be used in JavaScript to make it easy to refer to the element, with `document.getElementById('this')`. If it not used in any way in the document, it can be assumed to be there for possible future use. It might also have been added by some software (CMS or other) that generates the page and routinely adds `id` attributes to elements.